# rails subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I went to this tutorial [http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?autoplay=true) and trying to implement in http://ngtv2.info

but after I place the code in routes.rb

*match '/' => 'projects#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }*

and then typed [kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info](http://kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info)

the browser says that "Server not found", *Firefox can't find the server at kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to setup your DNS to point to your webserver. Just telling Rails to answer for a specific domain doesn't setup the DNS to do the same.

```
$ nslookup kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info
** server can't find kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info: NXDOMAIN
```

Use the interface of your domain provider or ask them directly to setup a wildcard DNS entry.

If you are using Rails 3 you shouldn't be using that Railscast (it's from 2008 anyway). There's a newer version which is specifically targeted for Rails 3: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

By the way: You should not deploy a yet unfinished app without any protection. Development should happen locally or *at least* behind a password secured website.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I watched both of those ScreenCast I just pasted the wrong URL sorry, anyways I edit question regarding on that video.

I only deploy it so that I can try the subdomain if it is really working cause in screencast they just use localhost, thats why...

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: What I really want to do is when someones signing up, they have the ability to use their username as a subdomain for ngtv2.info. Any idea on how to accomplish this thing?

Comment: As I said, you'll have to setup a wildcard record for your domain. After that it all depends on what you want to accomplish. I suggest you just start to build the app as normal and try to move to the subdomains later (will make development a lot easier).

Comment: Sorry for asking this, I am new on using rails so..

wonder what this means `$ nslookup kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info
** server can't find kingpangilinan.ngtv2.info: NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 4):

This has got **nothing** to do with Rails and everything to do with DNS and the way the Internet works.

You **must** configure the DNS zone for ngtv2.info with a wildcard subdomain entry before you can try setting up Rails to catch these subdomains.

To test subdomain routing out locally, you **should** try running the app on your computer and browsing to it at `http://lvh.me:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000`. Then you can also browse to `http://anysubdomain.lvh.me:3000` and Rails will catch that it's a subdomain.

Comment: I have my application running on WEBrick in development mode, navigating to `http://lvh.me:3000` doesn't lead anywhere and I get the server not found error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop on your local machine using the subdomain constraint modify your /etc/hosts by adding

```
127.0.0.1       SUBDOMAIN.localhost.de
```

Then rails can infer the subdomain from your request. Make sure you use the URL you specified in the /etc/hosts and not localhost:3000.